# I can not find the problem with my MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I get a Syntax error on mysql query which I don't quite understand what is the problem with it.

```
UPDATE w SET w.`unit`= "3" 
FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM user_extra AS w 
            LEFT JOIN users AS s ON w.user_id = s.id
     )
WHERE s.`unit` = "Turkish"
```

Above code is my query which get Syntax error around "FROM" part.

Comment: You cannot declare from after set. You need to do it before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you use is not valid for MySql.
Use a join of the 2 tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE user_extra w 
INNER JOIN users s ON w.user_id = s.id
SET w.`unit` =  '3' 
WHERE s.`unit` = 'Turkish'
```

I changed the join to an `INNER` join because the `WHERE` clause returns only the matched rows.